# Echo the bottom line of a CSV

Tags: php, csv, echo

I am attempting to echo the bottom line only of a .csv file. I echo the file in reverse order (as shown below) but I'm not sure how to only echo the top line of this. Please note that the csv variable, constantly changing.

Here is my php:

```html
<?php
$file = file("file.csv");
$file = array_reverse($file);
foreach($file as $f){
    echo $f."<br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is.

```
$file = "file.csv";
$data = file($file);
$last_line = $data[count($data)-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the `end` function see http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

```
<?php
$file = file("file.csv"); // You take care of reading all the lines.
$lastline = end($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = file("file.csv");
$last_line=count($file)-1;
echo $file[$last_line];
?>
```